# Google Assistant in React Native Project?

Tags: react-native, google-assistant

I am trying to implement a feature that would prompt user to say something (automatically and show "Speak Again" or something similar if user isn't saying something) and when the user is done speaking I would use the audio + (audio in text format) for further processing. Right now I am seeing Google Assistant already does similar stuff in android phones. I am looking for a way to use Google Assistant for my purpose, but couldn't find any proper resource.

Comment: You Can Use Text To Speech Converter for Audio. And Use ML For The Replies

Comment: I am trying to utilize Android phone's google assistant or something similar somehow. Not trying to build my own ML Model/Backend service for this purpose

Comment: Then This Should Help You https://github.com/innFactory/react-native-dialogflow

Comment: Alan AI is also a good solution for this.